# Find the complement of the subspace $U = {\{(x,y, x + y, x-y, 2x ) \in F^5, x,y \in F }\}$ in $F_5$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question:

> Suppose $U = {\{(x,y, x + y, x-y, 2x ) \in F^5, x,y \in F }\}$ . Find a subspace $W$ of $F^5$ such that $F^5 = U \oplus W$.

**Attempt:** We need to show that if $U,W$ are subspaces of $ V$ , then $U + W$ is a direct sum if and only if $U \cap W $ is empty.

Let $W = {\{(0,0,a,b,c) : a,b,c \in F}\}$.
Then let $z = (z_1,z_2,z_3, z_4, z_5) \in F^5$.
Then  $z = (z_1,z_2,z_3, z_4, z_5)= (z_1,z_2,z_1+z_2,z_1-z_2, 2z_1) + (0,0,a,b,c)$.

So solving these equations for $a,b,c$ we get $z = (z_1,z_2,z_3, z_4, z_5)= (z_1,z_2,z_1+z_2,z_1-z_2, 2z_1) + (0,0,z_3 - z_1 -z_2,z_4 - z_1 + z_2,z_5 - 2z_1)$.

So this a direct sum.
And we can see their intersection is empty.

Can someone please help me? Any help would be appreciated.
I am not sure if this is a way to approach it. Thank you.

Comment: is the complement the same thing? IT says find a subspace only

Comment: Your "attempt" is very weird: you seem to be trying to achieve something different from what you ask at the top!

Comment: I am trying to find a subspace such that when i add it it gives me $F^5$. What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a basis for $\;U\;$ , say:

$$\begin{cases}x=0,y=1\;\implies (0,1,1,-1,0)\\{}\\x=1,y=0\;\implies (1,0,1,1,2)\end{cases}$$

Now complete the above to a basis of the whole $\;F^5\;$ , say by means of adjoining elements of the standard basis. Thus, form a matrix with the two above vectors and the ones from the standard basis, reduce it by rows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1&2\\
0&1&1&\!\!-1&0\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1&2\\
0&1&1&\!\!-1&0\\
0&0&\!\!-1&\!\!-1&\!\!-2\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1&2\\
0&1&1&\!\!-1&0\\
0&0&\!\!-1&\!\!-1&\!\!-2\\
0&0&\!\!-1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow$$$${}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1&2\\
0&1&1&\!\!-1&0\\
0&0&\!\!-1&\!\!-1&\!\!-2\\
0&0&0&2&2\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1&2\\
0&1&1&\!\!-1&0\\
0&0&\!\!-1&\!\!-1&\!\!-2\\
0&0&0&2&2\\
0&0&0&\!\!-1&\!\!-2\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1&2\\
0&1&1&\!\!-1&0\\
0&0&\!\!-1&\!\!-1&\!\!-2\\
0&0&0&2&2\\
0&0&0&\!\!-1&\!\!-2\\
0&0&0&0&\!\!-2\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

and you can take the vectors of the third, fourth and fifth *original* rows to form your $\;W\,-$  basis